# python grid spacing for calculator app

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, grid, calculator

[What I'm trying to achieve](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sYAME.png)

[What I have](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2ezrm.png)

I am trying to make the AC button and the "0" button larger. How can I do this without messing up my for loop? I have tried columnspan and it does not work for me.

```
buttons = [['AC' , '%', '+' ],
           ['7' , '8' , '9' , '-' ],
           ['4' , '5' , '6' , '*' ],
           ['1' , '2' , '3' , '/' ],
           ['0' , '.' , '=' ]]

for r in range(len(buttons)):
    for c in range(len(buttons[r])):

        def cmd(x = buttons[r][c]):
            self.click(x)

        b = Button(self,
                   text = buttons[r][c],
                   width = 3,
                   relief = RAISED,
                   command = cmd)
        b.grid(row = r + 1, column = c)
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe have a dictionary of button names and size values:

```
bsize = {'AC':6,'0':6,'1':3,'2':3 ...}
```

then reference it when defining the size to place:

```
buttons = [['AC' , '%', '+' ],
           ['7' , '8' , '9' , '-' ],
           ['4' , '5' , '6' , '*' ],
           ['1' , '2' , '3' , '/' ],
           ['0' , '.' , '=' ]]

for r in range(len(buttons)):
    for c in range(len(buttons[r])):

        def cmd(x = buttons[r][c]):
            self.click(x)

        b = Button(self,
                   text = buttons[r][c],
                   width = bsize[buttons[r][c]],
                   relief = RAISED,
                   command = cmd)
        b.grid(row = r + 1, column = c)
```

You may also need to change the b.grid() args.

Answer (score 0):

You need to give the AC and zero buttons a columnspan of 2. That turns out to be a little awkward with your current architecture, but you could try something like this:

```
buttons = [['AC' , None, '%', '+' ],
           ['7' , '8' , '9' , '-' ],
           ['4' , '5' , '6' , '*' ],
           ['1' , '2' , '3' , '/' ],
           ['0' , None '.' , '=' ]]

for r in range(len(buttons)):
    for c in range(len(buttons[r])):

        if buttons[r][c] is None:
            continue
        def cmd(x = buttons[r][c]):
            self.click(x)

        b = Button(self,
                   text = buttons[r][c],
                   width = 3,
                   relief = RAISED,
                   command = cmd)
        if buttons[r][c] in ['AC', '0']:
            b.grid(row = r + 1, column = c, columnspan=2, sticky='EW')
        else:
            b.grid(row = r + 1, column = c)
```

Although, I might suggest something more like this:

```
buttons = [
    ('AC', 0, 0, 2),
    ('%', 0, 2, 1),
    ('+', 0, 3, 1),
    ('7', 1, 0, 1),
    ('8', 1, 1, 1),
    ('9', 1, 2, 1),
    ('-', 1, 3, 1),
    ('4', 2, 0, 1),
    ('5', 2, 1, 1),
    ('6', 2, 2, 1),
    ('*', 2, 3, 1),
    ('1', 3, 0, 1),
    ('2', 3, 1, 1),
    ('3', 3, 2, 1),
    ('/', 3, 3, 1),
    ('0', 4, 0, 2),
    ('.', 4, 2, 1),
    ('=', 4, 3, 1)]


for label, row, column, span in buttons:
    def cmd(x=label):
        self.click(x)

    b = tkinter.Button(root,
               text = label,
               width = 3,
               relief = tkinter.RAISED,
               command = cmd)
    b.grid(row=row, column=column, columnspan=span, sticky='EW')

root.mainloop()
```

This has the benefit of being a little more explicit with a little less hacky-ness.